# Powershell Azure deploy errs when client machine unattended

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying a reasonably large azure ARM template to set up a complete environment (some databases, some VMs, some scalesets etc...). Some of the items take a while to provision. For example I set up a Gateway so that I can connect to my build/deploy vnet, and this can take up to 30 minutes at times. I'm also installing base requirements on the VMs using Chocolatey. The entire provisioning script may take 45 minutes.  Because of this, I will sometimes let the job run and lock my machine.

What I notice is that when doing this, I will sometimes get a "Task Cancelled" exception at some point during the script (only when it is left unattended/machine is locked). Usually it appears that the script runs to completion and everything is there, but the return of the task cancelled exception is worrisome. Is there some alternate approach to running the ARM templates such that they don't require attended execution to complete successfully?

Comment: Deploy the template to Azure portal and let it run there instead of your local machine.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - Can you expound on that thought? How is what you're suggesting different than this (what I am doing): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/

Comment: [Ah, you would apparently have to covert it to JSON to use the portal.](http://rickrainey.com/2016/03/21/deploy-an-azure-resource-manage-template/)

Comment: What about setting your client machine's HDD turn off period to a longer timespan?

Comment: @juvchan - I believe this worked...In my case I'm on a Mac and using a VM hosting Win. The windows disks were set to never shut down...but the host Mac OS was shutting down disks after a while...seems like after I set it not to shut off disks on the mac I stopped seeing the job dying.

Comment: That's great to hear that this works for you